# How to create a clean url for user profile in django

Tags: django, html, python-3.x

I am building  an application . One of the functionalities of this application is to display objects created by users to other users when they login .Lets call these objects created by users (x).

Each of these objects displays the name of the user who created it . Bellow is my  code  of my view to display all objects created by users.

```
def CreatedObjects(request):
    objects=Model-Class-Name.objects.all()
# to display all users .
    users=User.objects.all()
    template_name="blabla.html"
    context={"objects":objects,"users":users}
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

my html file

```
<div class="objects>
<!--Display all available objects created by users-->
{% for obj in objects %}
 <!--Display the name of the user who created object, with a link that will take you to user profile  of this user -->
<div class="user'>
{% for user in users %}
<a href="{% url 'app_namespace:url_name' user.pk %}">{{obj.user.username}}
</div>

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<div>
```

The userprofile link  works  ,but since i am using a for loop to loop through available users in the database  ,the user name is displayed repeatedly . So my problem is how to avoid this .How can i create a userprfile link without for looping or how can i avoid the user name not to  be displayed continuously on a single object .

Comment: You're trying to display the creator of each object with a link to that creator's profile? I'm not sure why you're even looping through users if that's the case. Use `{{ obj.user.username }}` the way you have it for the url.

Comment: Thank you very much .It works perfectly .I am grateful